# Remove element of list until getting to the first empty one in Python

Tags: python, string, list, filter

I have this list of strings

```
list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '', '    5', '    ', '    6', '', '']
```

and I want to get every item after the first empty string to get this result

```
list = ['    5', '    ', '    6', '', '']
```

note that I want to leave the empty strings that comes after

I wrote this function:

```
def get_message_text(list):
    for i, item in enumerate(list):
        del list[i]
        if item == '':
            break
    return list
```

but I am getting this wrong results for no reason I know:

```
['2', '4', '    5', '    ', '    6', '', '']
```

any help ?

Comment: never change a list while iterating on it

Comment: Jean-François Fabre, I can see now what I did wrong, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just find the index of the first empty string and slice on it:

```py
def get_message_text(lst):
    try:
        return lst[lst.index("") + 1:]
    except ValueError:  # '' is not in list
        return [] # if there's no empty string then don't return anything
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a generator that drops while empty string not yet found.

Use `list(get_message_text(lst))` if you need a list,

otherwise use generator in `for` expression

`for e in get_message_text(lst):`

```
def get_message_text(lst):
    output = False
    for e in lst:
        if not output:
            if e == '': output = True
            continue
        yield e
```